# Form Builder GUI for PHP

Tags: php, html, user-interface, forms

I'm looking around for an open source form building package for PHP, and figured the hive-mob-mind of StackOverflow might be able to tilt me in the right direction.

Specifically, I'm looking for a form/survey builder application.  I want something that lets an end user use a web based GUI to create and configure/surveys and web-based forms.

What are the de-facto standard tools/packages that people use for this kind of thing these days.  I'm interested in software packages, **not** in hosted services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a stand-alone package, but I know some CMS solutions have this. Maybe you could look into their code base and if it's modulare use it in your project.

One I know of that uses it is [WebSiteBaker](http://php.opensourcecms.com/scripts/details.php?scriptid=69&name=Website%20Baker). Don't know if the code is any good thoug.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking to create something for a in-house CMS.  I'd like to start with some generic clean code and build off that.  Good info though.

Answer (score 3):

php-form-builder-class is an open-source project hosted on Google's Project Hosting service - http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/.  There are many examples included to get you started quickly.  I don't believe there is currently a GUI provided for end users to build forms though.  I use this in my development and would recommend.

Answer (score 2):

Hey you should check the **jquery.formbuilder** by botskonet on github in URL:

[jquery.formbuilder](https://github.com/shgninc/jquery.formbuilder/archive/master.zip)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something with a GUI that your users can use to make forms...

Try this..

http://blog.sonuku.com/2009/04/11/php-formbuilder/

-FT

Answer (score 0):

[Apponitro pForm](http://www.phpform.org/) is the only thing I've ever seen with a GUI.  You still have to paste the code into your page (and write the handler).  They have a paid version [MachForm](http://www.appnitro.com/?ref=pform) with more features.  I've never used them so I can't make any recommendations.